# Facebook Audience Network cause NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, facebook, nullpointerexception, facebook-audience-network

I experienced a lot of crash in my app using ads from [Facebook’s Audience Network](https://www.facebook.com/business/news/audience-network).Here is the report:

> NullPointerException (@FBInterstitial:InitInterstitialAd:-1)
>   {Thread:main
>   Exception:java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   android.webkit.WebSettingsClassic.getDefaultUserAgentForLocale(WebSettingsClassic.java:453)
>   at
>   android.webkit.WebViewClassic$Factory.getDefaultUserAgent(WebViewClassic.java:1503)
>   at
>   android.webkit.WebSettings.getDefaultUserAgent(WebSettings.java:1280)
>   at com.facebook.ads.a.s.a(Unknown Source) at
>   com.facebook.ads.a.s.a(Unknown Source) at
>   com.facebook.ads.a.j.(Unknown Source) at
>   com.facebook.ads.a.k.b(Unknown Source) at
>   com.facebook.ads.InterstitialAd.loadAd(Unknown Source)

It happens at `mInterstitialAd.show();`  where `mInterstitialAd` is instance of facebook InterstitialAd and it call show() method of `InterstitialAd`  class.

I also did check nullability for `mInterstitialAd` as

```
  if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isAdLoaded()) {
      mInterstitialAd.show();
    }
```

As you can see the error prompt when try to show a new ad. Anyone that has this error know how to solve it?

Note : I am using `AudienceNetwork.jar` file.And from log it seems that error in method `a` of class `s` (see code below) which is in `com.facebook.ads.a` package (available in jar file.)

```
  // IntelliJ API Decompiler stub source generated from a class file
  // Implementation of methods is not available

package com.facebook.ads.a;

public class s {
    private static java.lang.String a;

    public static void a(android.webkit.WebView webView, android.webkit.WebViewClient webViewClient, com.facebook.ads.a.r r) { /* compiled code */ }

    public static void a(android.webkit.WebView webView) { /* compiled code */ }

    public static java.lang.String a() { /* compiled code */ }

    public static java.lang.String a(android.content.Context context, com.facebook.ads.a.o o) { /* compiled code */ }

    private static java.lang.String a(android.content.Context context, java.lang.String s, java.lang.String s1) { /* compiled code */ }

    @android.annotation.TargetApi(17)
    private static java.lang.String a(android.content.Context context) { /* compiled code */ }
}
```

**Edit**
Initialize it as

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(mContext, "FaceBookPlacementID");
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(this);
mInterstitialAd.loadAd();
```

Comment: NullPointer means have you initialized it?

Comment: Yes,Nullpointer at   `mInterstitialAd.show();` ,As I also explain log.

Comment: What version of the audience network/SDK are you using?

Comment: @MingLi I am using jar file from  SDK version `v4.1.0` and followed step given in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/getting-started#ads_sdk

Comment: did you solved this ?

Comment: update sdk version,solved.

Answer (score 1):

Looks very similar to this issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/SX9yb3F_PNk

But we can surround the call from our SDK with a try/catch that has a fallback to grab the UA a different way. Will put out a hotfix tomorrow. Please report back if you still see the issue in 4.1.1.

Comment: Yes,exactly.But what's the solution,please reply if you update the SDK.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think you can do anything directly to fix this outside the SDK, but 4.1.1 is now out. Let me know if you still see the issue: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android

Comment: Ok,I will udpate my app with new sdk verision,and would accept if there is no issue regarding this question.Till then +1.

Comment: @JennyAbrahamson is they any solution for same issue?